# Webpack 4: mini-css-extract-plugin + sass-loader + splitChunks

Tags: css, webpack, sass, sass-loader, webpack-4

I've the follow example configuration to use mini-css-extract-plugin with Webpack 4:

```
entry: {
   a: ['./js/a.js', './scss/a.scss'],
   b: ['./js/b.js', './scss/b.scss']
},
module: {
    rules: [
       [...],
       {
        test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
        use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                    importLoaders: 2,
                    sourceMap: true
                }
            },
            {
                loader: 'postcss-loader',
                options: {
                    plugins: () => [
                        require('autoprefixer')
                    ],
                    sourceMap: true
                }
            },
            {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true
                }
            }
        ]
},
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            js: {
                test: /\.js$/,
                name: "commons",
                chunks: "all",
                minChunks: 7,
            },
            css: {
                test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
                name: "commons",
                chunks: "all",
                minChunks: 2,
            }
        }
    }
},
plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "dist/[name].css",
    }),
]
```

And the following sass files:

```
// a.scss
@import 'libA.scss';
@import 'libB.css';
[...] 

// b.scss
@import 'libA.scss';
@import 'libB.css';
[...]
```

When I run webpack `libB.css` is inserted in in `commons.css` bundle while `libA.scss` not.

In general every import of `.css` file get processed by splitChunks option (only if extension `css` is specified in the name) while sass import not.

I have a project with multiple sass entry point and many @import of sass component and I'd like to create a common bundle with shared sass modules.

Comment: I never worked with mini-css-extract-plugin, but I have worked with ExtractTextPlugin for css, and one thing that might help you is to put the loaders together in order to process your css.

ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader'])

Could be an idea to follow for your problem.

Comment: I think that mini-css-extract-plug has no method call "extract". In the documentation the loader are written all on the same array like my example (`MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader` then `css-loader`, etc...)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a similar issue, but this post helped me a lot - basically just using the @next version (the rest of my set up was similar to yours)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803260/how-to-use-webpack-4-splitchunksplugin-with-htmlwebpackplugin-for-multiple-page

Answer (score 29):

im doing someting like this in my Webpack 4 configuration.

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin")

module: {
rules: [ {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
      MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      {
        loader: "css-loader",
        options: {
          modules: true,
          sourceMap: true,
          importLoader: 2
        }
      },
      "sass-loader"
    ]}
  ]
},

plugins: [
  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
    // both options are optional
    filename: "style.css",
    chunkFilename: "[name].css"
  })
]
```

I also give `output.publicPath` -configuration object to point into my build dir,  example ->

```
output: {
   filename: "[name]-min.js",
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
   publicPath: "/static/react/dist/"
},
```

> **edit** If you are interested in code splitting, Webpack 4 can do this "out of the box" for you. This will split `.js` and as well `.css` -files for you in case you use dynamic imports.

```
optimization: {
  splitChunks: {
    chunks: 'all'
  }
}
```

If you other hand would like to merge only your `.css` into one file you could add as follow.

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all'
      cacheGroups: {
        styles: {
          name: 'styles',
          test: /\.s?css$/,
          chunks: 'all',
          minChunks: 1,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
          enforce: true,
        },
      }
    },
}
```

Comment: With this config webpack will merge all css in one but also will generate `styles.js` which is needed in order to make everything working (all the bundled js). Any way to get rid of that file?

Comment: Does this handle `@import 'md/variables'` where the expected resolved file is `./md/_variables.scss`?

Comment: Wrong api schema. cacheGroups goes inside splitChunks.

Comment: @nass600 Use `webpack-fix-style-only-entries` webpack plugin, works fine.

Comment: `importLoader` should be `importLoaders` and should probably be 1 not 2 in the initial config example

Comment: @ElYobo if you do NOT wish to use `SASS` 1 is correct value, 2 is used with `SASS`. It seems that `importLoaders` key is documented but seems to work either way.

Comment: 0 would be no loaders, 1 would be sass... presumably like with the importLoader typo they're also handling too many loaders being specified?  See the documented example here if there's confusion - https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#importloaders