# How to use Webpack 4 SplitChunksPlugin with HtmlWebpackPlugin for Multiple Page Application?

Tags: javascript, webpack, build-tools, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-4

I'm trying to utilize the SplitChunksPlugin to produce separate bundles per each page/template in a MPA. When I use the HtmlWebpackPlugin, I get an html file for each page with a script tag pointing to the correct bundle. That is great! However, the trouble I'm having is with my vendor files.  I want separate html files to point to only the vendor bundles they need. I can't get each separate html file to point to the correct vendor bundles when the SplitChunksPlugin creates multiple vendor bundles.  The bundles produced are:

```
home.bundle.js
product.bundle.js
cart.bundle.js
vendors~cart~home~product.bundle.js
vendors~cart~product.bundle.js
```

So basically the home template should reference home.bundle.js, vendors~cart~home~product.bundle.js, and not the second vendor bundle.  Only the cart and product templates should reference both vendor bundles.  I am utilizing the chunks option for the HtmlWebpackPlugin but can't get it to pull the correct vendor bundles unless I explicitly reference the name of it like so:

```
chunks: ['vendors~cart~home~product.bundle','home']
```

But this kinda defeats the purpose of dynamically rendering your script tags.  I've tried creating a vendor entry point but this lumps all my vendors together. 
Is there some simple config I'm missing?

My webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const Visualizer = require('webpack-visualizer-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    entry: {
        home: './src/js/page-types/home.js',
        product: './src/js/page-types/product.js',
        cart: './src/js/page-types/cart.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js')
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all'
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        new Visualizer(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'home.html',
            chunks: ['vendors','home']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'product.html',
            chunks: ['vendors','product']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'cart.html',
            chunks: ['vendors~cart~product','cart']
        }),
    ], ...
```

My js modules:

```
/* home.js */
    import jQuery from 'jquery';
    import 'bootstrap';
```

cart and product also reference the react library:

```
/* cart.js */
    import jQuery from 'jquery';
    import 'bootstrap';
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

```
/* product.js */
    import jQuery from 'jquery';
    import 'bootstrap';
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

Example html output home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Webpack App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="home.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: wouldn't each chunk will have react, jquery and bootstrap ? ideally we want them to be in a separate vendor file so it won't get copied to each chunk?

Comment: @anvarik very good question.  I know I had the same question originally because we don't want the browser to have to repeat the download of a library over and over again.  That would be counter to the performance we are trying to achieve.  Luckily, webpack already automagically takes care of this via the SplitChunksPlugin.  It will intelligently split out all of your vendors into separate bundles and smush some together into a single bundle depending on how you have imported them. You can view the documentation for that here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#splitchunksplugin

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use version4 of html-webpack-plugin (which is in beta now), and only include the entry chunk in the chunks option.

```
npm i -D html-webpack-plugin@next
```

and

```
module.exports = {
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'home.html',
        chunks: ['home']
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'product.html',
        chunks: ['product']
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'cart.html',
        chunks: ['cart']
    }),
};
```

This will include related chunks automatically.

Comment: I actually extended a method in the HtmlWebpackPlugin version 3 to solve this the first time but didn't like my solution.  For another project, I used this solution.  @nilptr this works brilliantly with the new version 4 beta.  Thanks!

Comment: @Dave for the curious few who'd rather still use HtmlWebpackPlugin 3, would you mind giving a synopsis of your solution as an answer?  I don't think management would be too fond of me using beta software.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to manually create your vendor chunks and then include whichever of those chunks needed for a page in the `chunks` option of `HtmlWebpackPlugin`.

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const Visualizer = require('webpack-visualizer-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    entry: {
        home: './src/js/page-types/home.js',
        product: './src/js/page-types/product.js',
        cart: './src/js/page-types/cart.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js')
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                'vendor-bootstrap': {
                    name: 'vendor-bootstrap',
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](jquery|bootstrap)[\\/]/,
                    chunks: 'initial',
                    priority: 2
                },
                'vendor-react': {
                    name: 'vendor-react',
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]react.*?[\\/]/,
                    chunks: 'initial',
                    priority: 2
                },
                'vendor-all': {
                    name: 'vendor-all',
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    chunks: 'initial',
                    priority: 1
                },
            }
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        new Visualizer(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'home.html',
            chunks: ['vendor-bootstrap', 'vendor-all', 'home']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'product.html',
            chunks: ['vendor-bootstrap', 'vendor-react', 'vendor-all', 'product']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'cart.html',
            chunks: ['vendor-bootstrap', 'vendor-react', 'vendor-all', 'cart']
        }),
    ], ...
```

The `vendor-all` chunk is to catch any other vendor libraries that are not included in the other chunks.

Comment: Good attempt. But I would never recommend this approach for my project. Maintaining these chunks & module dependencies would be so annoying.

Comment: This is hard to maintain in the long run, the html-webpack-plugin's 4.x version is smart enough to include the right set of chunks inside the template without further configuration, this is something I would recommend to use.

Comment: @dennisbot Yes, Tried it, Working like a charm.

Comment: In html-webpack-plugin 5 this answer is correct. Without specifying the chunks for each html file, the plugin doesn't know which entry file you want to use. See here: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/1729#issuecomment-1132448260
Also because Webpack is code-as-configuration you can define a single list of entry points and use loops.